# Javascript: How can i use /core functions in app/js/services/controllers Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

(ANGULAR-JS)

I have function locationChange(x,y) which takes 2 args and the function is located in core/services.

```
var locationChange = function(x, y) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ---
```

Now i want to use that function in app/js/services/controllers, and I don't know how to.

```
angularApp.controller('EditLocationController,function(...'
```

What are the steps to linking it?

Comment: Are you using Angularjs? Angular 1.x.x

Comment: Yes i am! edited.

Comment: Create a service with the `locationChange` function and inject that service in the controller to use the function.

Comment: 31piy is that the only way?

Comment: 31piy, do i need to make service with locationChange in core or in app/js?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the OP modified the post specifying that they're talking about the previous version of Angular, but the logic shouldn't change. Create a service and inject it into your component.

I assume you are talking about angular (v2+) and not AngularJS.

usually, you would define your methods in a service, like:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService{

  constructor() { }

  myMethod(): {
    ...
  }

}
```

You can then inject the service into a component to use its methods, as in:

```
import { MyService} from '...';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...']
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private service: MyService) { }

  this.service.myMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS 1, you can create a new service module who hold your function and use it in your directive.

> Service

```
(function() {
   'use strict';

   // Implementation of service
   angular.module('your.library.module', [])
   .factory('mylib', function() {

     return {
       locationChange : function(x, y) {
         ...
       }, 
       myOtherFunction : function() {
         ...
       }
   }
});
```

> Directive

```
(function() {
   'use strict';    

   angularApp = angular.module('your.module', [ 'your.library.module' ]);
   ...
   angularApp.controller('EditLocationController', ['mylib', function(mylib) {
      mylib.locationChange (x,y);
   }]);
})
```